# In a WPF tabControl how can I dynamically select a tab page from an object's type?

Tags: c, wpf, xaml, mvvm, tabcontrol

I've implemented the MVVM pattern and have some viewModels that are bound to tab pages on a tab control.

When a specific object type changes (i.e. from Car myVehical, to Bike myVehical), then i want the relevant tab page to become selected.

Thanks.

Comment: How does an object type change dynamically?  Do you have a vehicle base blass and two derived classes: car and bike?

Comment: Yes pretty much.  Specifically the user will change the object by selecting a different item from a combobox

Comment: @HAdes - Ok, I think I get where you're coming from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *hack* it by using a custom `IValueConverter`. You could then bind `TabControl.SelectedIndex` to a property on your view model and use the converter to convert from the type (Car or Bike) to an index. The value converter code would have to be updated when you change the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a tab control, you can use DataTemplates.  The view itself will get set automatically based on the object you set as the content.

Comment: ok, so how would that look as I still want the same look and feel as tab pages, i.e user can still select other tabs if necessary.  sorry i'm new and never used datatemplates yet. thanks